# Debian: gpg: error reading '[stdin]': General error

Tags: linux, debian

I'm creating a new workspace for a project and use Debian 9 inside the VB in a MacBook Pro, El Capitan. For the Java 8, I have the instructions like,

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/java8.list with this content:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, I went to the terminal and type,

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/java8.list
```

Then, I paste the mentioned content into the file, saved and closed. Afterwards, when I execute the command,

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
```

I get this error stack,

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.Nrr9YiY2yQ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/run/user/1000/gnupg/d.efsrb3uyo6fh5yhoikm7bucx/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

I use the command `apt-get install dirmngr` to install the `dirmngr` and tried again in the terminal. This time I have the error,

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.A4f5OjYwxw/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
gpg: key C2518248EEA14886: public key "Launchpad VLC" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no writable keyring found: Not found
gpg: error reading '[stdin]': General error
gpg: import from '[stdin]' failed: General error
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I have next to zero knowledge about Linux/ Debian, so, what to do in this context? It seems that the `dirmngr` issue is gone for now

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try running command with sudo

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886